# How can I create a python program that can determine whether an email is a spam or not?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, email-spam

I'm new to python, and I want to create a program that can determine whether an email is a spam or not based on three factors.

The subject (if it's empty, it's spam), the sender (I only want people whose email addresses end with '`.com,`' for example, otherwise it's spam), and the date (I only want emails on non-weekend days, otherwise it's spam).

I did the subject part, and it works successfully.

The code is attached below. But I need help with the sender and the date part.

```
import pandas as pd
ExcelFile = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Email Table.xlsx')
Subject = pd.DataFrame(ExcelFile, columns=['Subject'])

def spam(Subject):
    df_multiindex = ExcelFile.set_index(['Subject'])
    n = len(df_multiindex)
    
    for x in range(n):
        if ((pd.isnull(ExcelFile.loc[x, 'Subject'])) == True):
            print("Spam")
        else:
            print("not spam")

spam(Subject)
```

Comment: What does `ExcelFile` look like? Provide a sample

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We are looking for a *specific* question in the post itself, not just the title summary; "But I need help with the sender and the date part." [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? What do you need help with, and what don't you understand about it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

You don't provide the format/type of your mail address, so this is just an idea. Check if the sender address ends with ".com":

```py
if address.endswith(".com"):
    print("Spam")
else:
    print("not spam")
```

You also do not provide information on how the date is formatted. Given a unix timestamp, it'd work like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

ts = 1652734079
dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
# Check if weekday is saturday/sunday
if dt_object.weekday() in [5, 6]:
    print("Spam")
else:
    print("not spam")
```